# Works with integer but not with variable. The input is took from input("")

Tags: python

I am having this issue. As i run my code in the console works perfectly, but in pyCharm doesen`t.

```
def shift_string(plain_text,no_poz):
    no_poz=no_poz*(-1)
    return (plain_text[no_poz:]+plain_text[:no_poz])
```

But if i use an integer, it works

```
def shift_string(plain_text):
    return (plain_text[-4:]+plain_text[:-4])
```

Comment: The Close-Votes are (likely) because you did not supply any examples of input and output, and no code showing how you use this. Use [edit] to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `python3` using `input()` returns the user input as `string`. maybe you are having that kind of problem in Pycharm. You can try converting the `no_poz` to `int`

But in `python` (i.e Python 2.7) if you use `input()` to take user input...then if you enter any integer, it will be stored as an `integer`

Maybe when you are running your code in console, you are using `python`
While your Pycharm interpreter uses python3.

Python 3.5.2

```
>>> c = input()
2
>>> type(c)
<class 'str'>
```

Python 2.7.12

```
>>> c = input()
2
>>> type(c)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I casted it before but i made the mistake to multiply the string with -1 . Ex: no_poz*=(-1) as it was already a string. But thanks yo.